# Authentication with google oauth and nestjs

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, nestjs

I want to use a guard for my routes controller based on the access token of google, but I don't know how to implement this.

I retrieve this from my google oauth

```
{
  "message": "User information from google",
  "user": {
    "email": "test@gmail.com",
    "firstName": "John",
    "lastName": "Kennedy",
    "picture": 
    "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/mypicture",
    "accessToken": "myaccesstoken"
  }
}
```

Now I don't know how to use this access token for my other routes, example in a controller:

```
  @UseGuards() // I don't know what to put here
  @Get('/get_customer/:id')
  async findCustomerById(@Param() params): Promise<Customer> {
    try {
      return await this.stripeService.findCustomerById(params.id);
    } catch (e) {
      throw new Error(e.message);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Use the OAuth to register and login, not to execute endpoints. Use the callback from Google to create an account and after it, use your basic guard on your created user.

Answer (score 1):

**Short Answer:**

Inside google's redirect endpoint, You can issue a JWT token to the user, which will hold their data as payload, and secure your endpoints with JWT verification guard.
See [this](https://blog.dominikwawrzynczak.pl/2020/08/oauth-with-nestjs-application-sign-in-with-google/)

**Long Answer:**

What google basically does is just provide your application with the identity of the user who used that service to log in... Specifically, google provides you with the user's data(with the scopes you defined) and an access token.

at this point, you have multiple approaches to guard your routes:

1. Issue a JWT token that holds this user data you got from google and return it to the user(the client), each request the user sends with that token you would be able to identify the user and give them access to routes (stateless way: the token will hold everything encrypted inside it) See [this](https://blog.dominikwawrzynczak.pl/2020/08/oauth-with-nestjs-application-sign-in-with-google/).
2. Store a session of this user that contains the data you got from google, and give them the SessionId that will make you(the server) identify the user later on and give them access to routes (stateful way: you need to store the session data somewhere).

You might wonder what is the use of the access token in all of this... generally, this token can only be used by **your** application (which has ClientId+ClientSecret you got from google) to access user's google data(defined by scopes you chose) on behalf of them. So basically this token is a **consent** from the user so your app can access their google data.

This, for example, can be useful if you can't store user's data in our database(for legal reasons), so you can directly query their data from google without consulting them every single time.

Comment: You state that the JWT ID-token should be used to provide claims as well as authentication. However, the ID-token should not authenticate the API. It should provide claims to the resource server (our server/API) for registration and client for authentication completion (profile image etc). Also the token is not encrypted, its signed. Lastly, the access_token is not only consent, it is a bridge to the IDP (in this case google) to verify authentication after the login consent procedure has completed. It can also be refreshed after expiry using the refresh_token.

Comment: My point is: only use the access_token for providing authentication in f.e. a Bearer authentication header, do NOT use the ID_TOKEN on API calls.